# The differences on the atmospheric transportation for various trace metal in atmosphere

Tags: geology, atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry, earth-observation, upper-atmosphere

I have known that the atmospheric lifetimes of chemical species were highly dependent on their physicochemical properties. For example, $SO_2$ might exist for 5-8 days, while $NO_2$ could only exist less than 1 day. As for the particular contents, the elemental carbon (EC) could undergo longer-range pathway compared to organic carbon (OC) since it was inert and had much less hydroscopicity which forbid the wet deposition.

When I studied on the atmospheric trace metals in aerosols, I have hardly found some literatures related with the differences between various trace metals (i.e., polluted elements Pb, Cu, Zn and crustal elements Al, Ca, Ti) in their transportation processes. Is there any key issues controlling the lifetime of trace metal in the atmosphere.

Any advices or recommended reading material would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I would expect the lifetime to depend on the containing aerosol rather than the element itself. But others will be more knowledgeable

Comment: I don´t think that you will find too much literature just because their concentration (parts per billion). Check [this](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/csd/assessments/ozone/1985/vol1/chapter3.pdf)